# How do I connect to an on-premise DB2 database to an application deployed in Bluemix

Tags: node.js, db2, ibm-cloud

I have a Node.js/JavaScript application deployed to Bluemix. I need my application to be able to connect to a DB2 datasource (connection string shown below).

The `lexbz181112.cloud.dst.ibm.com` is an IBM server running on premise.

What steps do I need to take to connect to this datasource from my application (which is running in Bluemix)? I don't want to change any of my application code in order to read/write from the database.

```
DRIVER={DB2};DATABASE=MYDB;HOSTNAME=lexbz181112.cloud.dst.ibm.com;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx;PORT=nnnnn;PROTOCOL=TCPIP
```

Comment: If that hostname isn't some name you made up to protect it from unwanted visitors, your first problem is that that server isn't known in dns, and thus not locatable on the internet.

Comment: I would look into API Connect and a Loopback DB2 Connector here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-db2. This might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same when you connect your application to remote database or cloud database, as long as you have hostname:port, database name and username/password.

If your application and database both on Bluemix, have you tried to bind this database service to your application directly?

Answer (score 0):

The Bluemix [Secure Gateway](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/secure-gateway) service is used in such cases. It establishes a secure, transparent bridge between your on-premises resource, in your case the DB2 server, and your cloud application. Because it is transparent to the application you don't need to change your application code. The secure connection is established from "on-prem" to the cloud, so that the on-prem administrators are in charge.

Some time I ago [I wrote a sample application to walk through all the steps](https://github.com/data-henrik/Bluemix-onprem-data) to create a scenario as described by you. You can find the [instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/data-henrik/Bluemix-onprem-data).

Answer (score 0):

If the host is reachable from the Internet you can simply access it from your application as you'd normally do, since a Bluemix application is able to connect to the Internet. The only improvement I'd do to this is to use a [user provided service instance](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html). It allows you to separate the DB connection parameters from the application code, avoiding to have those hard coded in the application.